# call Jquery function from Convform.js chatbot

Tags: html, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

How to call jquery function from Convform.js  chatbot question ?
I am facing issue my question is not getting post

```
<div data-conv-fork="search">
                                <div data-conv-case="N">
                                    <input type="text" name="refrencenu" data-conv-question="" data-callback="getinfo" /> // callback function to print question again
                                </div>
                                <div data-conv-case="R">
                                    <input type="text" name="refrencenu2" data-conv-question="Alright! First, tell me the Reference Number, please." data-callback="getinfo" />
                                </div>
                                <div data-conv-case="P">
                                    <input type="text" name="refrencenu3" data-conv-question="" data-callback="getinfo" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
    <script>
```

convstate to get the current state //function getinfo(convState, ready) {
$.ajax({
url: '<%=Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.FriendlyUrl.Resolve("../Code/AutoComplete.asmx/GetNumberDetails")%>',
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
data: "{ "number" : "" + convState.current.answer.value + ""   }",
success: function (response) {

```
    to move to next state //    convState.current.next = convState.newState({
                            type: 'text',
                            name: 'ddsearch'+count,
                            questions: ['Here are search results( top 10 ), ' + response.d],
                            noAnswer: true,
                            
                        });
                        convState.current.next.next=current;
                 
                    }, error: function (response) { alert(response.d); }
                });
                
            }</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please write Reday function at the end

```
 convState.current.next = convState.newState({
                            type: 'text',
                            name: 'ddsearch'+count,
                            questions: ['Here are search results( top 10 ), ' + response.d],
                            noAnswer: true,
                            
                        });
                        convState.current.next.next=current;
reday();// added code
                 
                    }, error: function (response) { alert(response.d); }
                });
                
            }</script>
```